# Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, spring

Estoy tratando de conectarme a mi `DB` por `MySQL` pe me sale ese error de `Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException` y no accede ni a ningún parámetro:

```js
jdbc.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/facturacion?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
jdbc.username = myuser
jdbc.password = mypassword
```

```css
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ifac.Config.MySQL.<init>(MySQL.java:43)
 at ifac.Config.MySQL$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$63df6b53.<init>(<generated>)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
 at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
 ... 63 more
```

```html
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Component
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
public class MySQL {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    private Connection conexion = null;

    public MySQL() {
        System.out.println("...........................................");
        System.out.println("...........................................");
//        System.out.println(environment.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
//        System.out.println(environment.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
//        System.out.println(environment.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
//        System.out.println(environment.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        System.out.println("..........................................");
        System.out.println("..........................................");
        try {
            String usuario = environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username");
            String password = environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password");
            Class.forName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
            String url = environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url");
            conexion = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, password);
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {

        }
    }

    public Connection getConexion() {
        return conexion;
    }

    public Connection cerrarConexion() {
        try {
            conexion.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        conexion = null;
        return conexion;
    }
}
```

Comment: Me suena a que tu variable environment no fue construida y la inyecta nula, puedes verificar si viene nula?

Comment: `@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})` u otra forma de hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

Sacado de https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html

```
NOTE: The DataSource interface, new in the JDBC 2.0 API, provides another way to connect to a data source. The use of a DataSource object is the preferred means of connecting to a data source.

As part of its initialization, the DriverManager class will attempt to load the driver classes referenced in the "jdbc.drivers" system property. This allows a user to customize the JDBC Drivers used by their applications. For example in your ~/.hotjava/properties file you might specify:

 jdbc.drivers=foo.bah.Driver:wombat.sql.Driver:bad.taste.ourDriver


The DriverManager methods getConnection and getDrivers have been enhanced to support the Java Standard Edition Service Provider mechanism. JDBC 4.0 Drivers must include the file META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver. This file contains the name of the JDBC drivers implementation of java.sql.Driver. For example, to load the my.sql.Driver class, the META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver file would contain the entry:

 my.sql.Driver
```

Mira a ver si te devuelve un objeta Connection la linea:

```
conexion = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, password);
```

Y ya de paso pon algo en el catch para que si te da error te enteres ;-) (un System.out.println() aunque sea )

Comment: no llega ni al error, se queda en `String usuario = environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username");` tratando de obtener el `username`, y aunque lo ponga, me devuelve el mismo `NullPointerException`

Comment: El error no lo tienes al coger el nombre del usuario, por lo que veo en el error.

Comment: Seguro que tienes la libreria de MYSQL correcta?. El error te lo da al invocar a la libreria MYSQL. Mira este manual: https://springframework.guru/configuring-spring-boot-for-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser problema por la versión de tu MySQL. A partir de la versión 8, la cadena de conexión varía.

Esta es una alternativa para tu archivo properties.yml (si deseas, puedes convertirlo de formato .yml a .properties). Este tipo de URL me ha funcionado al conectarme a un MySQL 8. Espero pueda ayudarte :)

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_database?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
    username: userName
    password: myPassword
  jpa:
    generate-ddl: true
```